# Parse nested elements in JSON

Tags: json, swift

I couldn't seem to parse the following json:

```
["data": {
    companies =     (
    );
    "login_status" = success;
    "rs_customer" =     {
        id = "<null>";
        name = "<null>";
        status = "<null>";
    };
    user =     {
        email = "email@email.com";
        id = 0;
        lastlogin = "06/14/16 12:44 am";
        name = "Jayson Tamayo";
        password = mypassword;
        phone = "112345";
    };
}, "status": success]
```

I retrieve that JSON thru:

```
HTTPGetJSON("http://myurl.com") {
                (data: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>, error: String?) -> Void in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error)
                } else {
                    print(data)
                    let status = data["status"] as? String
                    print(status)

                }
            }
```

When I print the "status" it works. But when I try to use data["name"] I get nil. I also tried data["data"]["name"] but I also get nil.

Comment: try data["user"]["name"].

Comment: I get `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: try data["data"]["user"]["name"] this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your main object is a dictionary.

In the "data" key, there's several values: "companies" is an array, "rs_customer" is a dictionary, the statuses are Strings and "user" is a dictionary.

So, to get the user, you would just have to cast to the proper types, something like this, if `data` is the object we see in the question:

```
if let content = data["data"] as? [String:AnyObject] {
    if let user = content["user"] as? [String:AnyObject] {
        if let name = user["name"] as? String {
            print(name)
        }   
    }
}
```

You can also chain the unwrapping for simpler code:

```
if let content = data["data"] as? [String:AnyObject],
        user = content["user"] as? [String:AnyObject],
        name = user["name"] as? String {
    print(name)
}
```

Comment: How is company an array @EricD?  "Data" itself is an array right?

Comment: @Dershowitz123 The whole thing is a dictionary, and the "data" field is also a dictionary. Only "companies" is an array.

Comment: I know this may sound off topic but if you could show us how to treat what elements as an array or a dictionary in a JSON, it'd really be helpful. Please share your expertise with us.

Comment: @Dershowitz123 OP's object looks like that is because it's a `[String:AnyObject]`, a dictionary with String keys and AnyObject values. But when we `print` such a dictionary where the compiler doesn't know the types of the contents, it tries to be smart but the results are weird: we see arrays as `()` and dicts as `[:]` *and* as `{}`. Make a test: if the dictionary would have been of know types, like `[String:[String:String]]` (just an example), it would have been printed without any format ambiguities. Also, be careful to not confuse Swift syntax with JSON syntax... *Confusing, I know ;)*

Comment: Still didn't understand @EricD. :(